# Moved wp-content and got problem with themes directory?

Tags: customization

I have moved the 'wp-content' directory to a new folder following the guide at [Moving Wp-content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content). I could able to access plugins directory with out any problem as I used the wp_content_dir in addition with WP_CONTENT_DIR' . But I could not able to access themes and unable to install new themes using theme repository.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );  
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');


define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins');
```

Edited the wp-config.php with these constraints

Does any one have idea on resolving the issue? I mean, how to access the themes? Also should I expect any trouble in the future for moving the wp-content?

Thank you!

Comment: I never get it to successfully install either. So what I usually do is, install wordpress, edit wp-config, and alter wp-content

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what do you mean by Alteration of wp-content? I can see that you asked similar question and @rarst answered you with a function -register_theme_directory() . Could you help me more about it if that worked for you? Thanks !

Comment: Just re-read your question above. Is your intent to move wp-content into a subdirectory, not on the same level as wp-admin and wp-includes? Or all your wp files are situated under blog?

Comment: I don't have any objection if it is at same level as wp-admin or elsewhere. So, the folder should be like ...public_html/new-custom-folder/site-content' instead of public_html/wp-content

Comment: If all you need is to move wordpress below public_html, then just do so. Create a subdirectory under public_html, then place all wordpress files inside, and install it from there. What else do you need?

Comment: I don't move WordPress installation. I have clearly mentioned in the question that ,I need to move the "wp-content " folder.(plugins,themes and anything else from wp-content)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can move wp-content one level below, but you can always try. Steps that I've been able to replicate: (1) install wordpress at its default state, (2) add defined paths for plugins and contents in wp-config.php, (3) move wp-content and rename plugins folder if you wish, (4) to rename the theme folder, it's a bit tricky, as register_theme_directory only works under theme files, so you have to add it to a theme, activate the theme, add the theme folder, move the desired theme you want, then go to appearance, you'll see your desired theme, activate and viola...

Answer (score 1):

Did you set these constants in `wp-config.php`? Btw. the plugin constants are optional.

On my development instance, I've set the following before `ABSPATH` and it works without any problems:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog/wp-content');
```

### Limiations:

a) If you use SSL, you should also check for the rigth protocol with `is_ssl()`.
b) Not every plugin in the repository is using these constants. Many plugins out there has hardcoded paths relative to the root directory. So you could run in some problems if you really need a thirtparty plugin.

Comment: Roman, Thanks for your kind response ! I am not using  SSL